# Can't select Primary Output as target of shortcut in Visual Studio 2005 setup project

Tags: deployment, visual-studio-2005, installation

I've Added a setup project to my solution (didn't use the wizard) I then added the primary output of the Windows Application I have coded to the Applcation Folder node (Right click the setup project in Solution-Explorer and select View -> File System). I Right clicked the User's Desktop node and selected 'Create Shortcut to user's Desktop' in the context menu. Typed a name for the shortcut and then in the properties window clicked the ellipsis button for the Target property. A dialog is displayed but it won't expand the Application folder node and let me select the Primary Output as the target !!! WTF ???

I have done this on another project but I can't for the life of me figure out why I can't do it on this one. Hell! the projects are almost identical in every other way. Gah! going bald. Hoping someone out there is having a better day than me and has time to give me the probably screamingly obvious solution and make me feel lame.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you've created a shortcut to the desktop, on the desktop.

Try clicking on User's Desktop, then right-clicking in the right hand pane, and selecting "Create new shortcut" from there.

Answer (score 2):

You actually have to right-click on 'Primary Output From ' in your setup project, and create a shortcut to that.  Then, you can move the shortcut over to the 'Users Desktop' location within your setup project.